# Julia - Gurobi Callbacks on array of JuMP variables

Tags: optimization, callback, julia, gurobi, julia-jump

In Gurobi and JuMP 0.21, it is well documented [here](https://github.com/jump-dev/Gurobi.jl) on how you would access a variable with a callback:

```
using JuMP, Gurobi, Test

model = direct_model(Gurobi.Optimizer())
@variable(model, 0 <= x <= 2.5, Int)
@variable(model, 0 <= y <= 2.5, Int)
@objective(model, Max, y)
cb_calls = Cint[]
function my_callback_function(cb_data, cb_where::Cint)
    # You can reference variables outside the function as normal
    push!(cb_calls, cb_where)
    # You can select where the callback is run
    if cb_where != GRB_CB_MIPSOL && cb_where != GRB_CB_MIPNODE
        return
    end
    # You can query a callback attribute using GRBcbget
    if cb_where == GRB_CB_MIPNODE
        resultP = Ref{Cint}()
        GRBcbget(cb_data, cb_where, GRB_CB_MIPNODE_STATUS, resultP)
        if resultP[] != GRB_OPTIMAL
            return  # Solution is something other than optimal.
        end
    end
    # Before querying `callback_value`, you must call:
    Gurobi.load_callback_variable_primal(cb_data, cb_where)
    x_val = callback_value(cb_data, x)
    y_val = callback_value(cb_data, y)
    # You can submit solver-independent MathOptInterface attributes such as
    # lazy constraints, user-cuts, and heuristic solutions.
    if y_val - x_val > 1 + 1e-6
        con = @build_constraint(y - x <= 1)
        MOI.submit(model, MOI.LazyConstraint(cb_data), con)
    elseif y_val + x_val > 3 + 1e-6
        con = @build_constraint(y + x <= 3)
        MOI.submit(model, MOI.LazyConstraint(cb_data), con)
    end
    if rand() < 0.1
        # You can terminate the callback as follows:
        GRBterminate(backend(model))
    end
    return
end
# You _must_ set this parameter if using lazy constraints.
MOI.set(model, MOI.RawParameter("LazyConstraints"), 1)
MOI.set(model, Gurobi.CallbackFunction(), my_callback_function)
optimize!(model)
@test termination_status(model) == MOI.OPTIMAL
@test primal_status(model) == MOI.FEASIBLE_POINT
@test value(x) == 1
@test value(y) == 2
```

i.e., you would use `x_val = callback_value(cb_data, x)`. However, how should you do when you have an array of variables with specific indexes not starting at 1, i.e. my variables are not in a vector but declared thanks to:

```
@variable(m, x[i=1:n, j=i+1:n], Bin)
```

Should I access `x` with double for loops on its two dimensions and call multiple times `callback_value`? If so, the indexes for `j` will not be the same, won't they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

```
x_val = callback_value.(Ref(cb_data), x)
```

Or just call `callback_value(cb_data, x[i, j])` when you need the value.

For example:

```
using JuMP, Gurobi
model = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer)
@variable(model, 0 <= x[i=1:3, j=i+1:3] <= 2.5, Int)
function my_callback_function(cb_data)
    x_val = callback_value.(Ref(cb_data), x)
    display(x_val)
    for i=1:3, j=i+1:3
        con = @build_constraint(x[i, j] <= floor(Int, x_val[i, j]))
        MOI.submit(model, MOI.LazyConstraint(cb_data), con)
    end
end
MOI.set(model, MOI.LazyConstraintCallback(), my_callback_function)
optimize!(model)
```

yields

```
julia> optimize!(model)
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.0 build v9.1.0rc0 (mac64)
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 8 logical processors, using up to 8 threads
Optimize a model with 0 rows, 3 columns and 0 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0x5d543c3a
Variable types: 0 continuous, 3 integer (0 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [0e+00, 0e+00]
  Objective range  [0e+00, 0e+00]
  Bounds range     [2e+00, 2e+00]
  RHS range        [0e+00, 0e+00]
JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{Float64,2,Tuple{Int64,Int64}} with 3 entries:
  [1, 2]  =  -0.0
  [2, 3]  =  -0.0
  [1, 3]  =  -0.0
JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{Float64,2,Tuple{Int64,Int64}} with 3 entries:
  [1, 2]  =  2.0
  [2, 3]  =  2.0
  [1, 3]  =  2.0
JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{Float64,2,Tuple{Int64,Int64}} with 3 entries:
  [1, 2]  =  2.0
  [2, 3]  =  2.0
  [1, 3]  =  2.0
JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{Float64,2,Tuple{Int64,Int64}} with 3 entries:
  [1, 2]  =  2.0
  [2, 3]  =  -0.0
  [1, 3]  =  -0.0
Presolve time: 0.00s
Presolved: 0 rows, 3 columns, 0 nonzeros
Variable types: 0 continuous, 3 integer (0 binary)
JuMP.Containers.SparseAxisArray{Float64,2,Tuple{Int64,Int64}} with 3 entries:
  [1, 2]  =  -0.0
  [2, 3]  =  -0.0
  [1, 3]  =  -0.0
Found heuristic solution: objective 0.0000000

Explored 0 nodes (0 simplex iterations) in 0.14 seconds
Thread count was 8 (of 8 available processors)

Solution count 1: 0 

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective 0.000000000000e+00, best bound 0.000000000000e+00, gap 0.0000%

User-callback calls 31, time in user-callback 0.14 sec
```

Comment: I think that does not work. It is not available to broadcast on the second argument of a function with `.(` operator, is it? Your second options is my current workaround. You have to call the function each time with this way and can't store it to an array of same indexes, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Try it; it does work. Here's the Julia documentation: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting

Comment: Yes, it will work but the indexes won't be the same, right? They will start at 1 for x_val as it becomes an array and not a JuMP variable anymore.

Comment: Again, please try it. It will return a `SparseAxisArray`. If it doesn't, that is a bug we need to fix.

Comment: Confirmed that it works. I added an example.

Comment: I figured out why it did not work, I used `x_val = callback_value(cb_data, x)` instead of `x_val = callback_value(Ref(cb_data), x)`. Thanks :)